# How to cancel an infinite stream from within the stream itself?

Tags: stream, rust, future, rust-tokio

I'm trying to cancel an interval (`interval_timer`) after emptying a queue but not sure what is the right strategy.

```
let mut some_vars = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
let interval_timer = tokio_timer::Timer::default();

let timer = interval_timer
    .interval(Duration::from_millis(1000))
    .map_err(|_| {
        println!("Errored out");
    });

let s = timer.for_each(move |_| {
    println!("Woke up");
    let item = some_vars.pop().unwrap();

    let f = futures::future::ok(item).map(|x| {
        println!("{:?}", x);
    });
    tokio::spawn(f)
});

tokio::run(s);
```

I tried `drop` as suggested in gitter but that ended up with an error:

```
let mut some_vars = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
let mut interval_timer = tokio_timer::Timer::default();

let timer = interval_timer
    .interval(Duration::from_millis(1000))
    .map_err(|_| {
        println!("Errored out");
    });

let s = timer.for_each(move |_| {
    println!("Woke up");
    if some_vars.len() == 1 {
        drop(interval_timer);
    }

    let item = some_vars.pop().unwrap();

    let f = futures::future::ok(item).map(|x| {
        println!("{:?}", x);
    });
    tokio::spawn(f)
});

tokio::run(s);
```

The error:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of captured outer variable in an `FnMut` closure
--> src/main.rs:72:22
   |
60 |     let mut interval_timer = tokio_timer::Timer::default();
   |         ------------------ captured outer variable
...
72 |                 drop(interval_timer);
   |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot move out of captured outer variable in an `FnMut` closure
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For cases where you want to cancel a stream from *outside* of the stream, see [stream-cancel](https://docs.rs/stream-cancel/0.4.4/stream_cancel/).

---

For your specific case, it's easiest to convert your collection into a stream  and zip it together with the interval timer. This way, the resulting stream naturally stops when the collection is empty:

```
use futures::{future, stream, Stream}; // 0.1.29
use std::time::Duration;
use tokio; // 0.1.22
use tokio_timer::Interval; // 0.2.11

fn main() {
    tokio::run({
        let some_vars = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];

        let timer =
            Interval::new_interval(Duration::from_millis(100)).map_err(|e| panic!("Error: {}", e));

        let some_vars = stream::iter_ok(some_vars.into_iter().rev());
        let combined = timer.zip(some_vars);

        combined.for_each(move |(_, item)| {
            eprintln!("Woke up");

            tokio::spawn(future::lazy(move || {
                println!("{:?}", item);
                Ok(())
            }));

            Ok(())
        })
    });
}
```

Otherwise, you can stop the stream by using `and_then` to both remove the value from the collection and control if the stream should continue:

```
use futures::{future, Stream}; // 0.1.29
use std::time::Duration;
use tokio; // 0.1.22
use tokio_timer::Interval; // 0.2.11

fn main() {
    tokio::run({
        let mut some_vars = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];

        let timer =
            Interval::new_interval(Duration::from_millis(100)).map_err(|e| panic!("Error: {}", e));

        let limited = timer.and_then(move |_| {
            if some_vars.len() <= 4 {
                Err(())
            } else {
                some_vars.pop().ok_or(())
            }
        });

        limited.for_each(move |item| {
            eprintln!("Woke up");

            tokio::spawn(future::lazy(move || {
                println!("{:?}", item);
                Ok(())
            }));

            Ok(())
        })
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a copy of Tokio's `Interval` struct, adding a reference to a method of my application to indicate when to interrupt early.

In my case, I want to interrupt the `Interval` to shutdown.

My Interval poll method looks like this:

```
fn poll(&mut self) -> Poll<Option<Self::Item>, Self::Error> {
    if self.session.read().unwrap().shutdown {
        return Ok(Async::Ready(Some(Instant::now())));
    }

    // Wait for the delay to be done
    let _ = match self.delay.poll() {
```

Then you need to keep a handle on the task (call `task = futures::task::current()` when running inside the timeout task).

At any point you can then call `task.notify()` to kick the interval into action and hit your break out code, interrupting the `Interval` early.

Inside `Interval` there is a `Delay` struct that can be modified, you could create an `Interval` that you can interrupt and change the timeout, this way you could interrupt once and then continue.

Answer (score -2):

`tokio_timer::Interval` implements `futures::Stream`, so try to use the [`take_while`](https://docs.rs/tokio-timer/0.1.2/tokio_timer/struct.Interval.html#method.take_while) method:

```
let s = timer
    .take_while(|()| 
        future::ok(is_net_completed()))
    .for_each(move |_| {
        println!("Woke up");
        // ...
    })
```

Comment: Can you explain further how this *cancels* the repeating interval?

Comment: I did try take_while, the issue I had with that was I couldn't use some_vars in take_while closure and also for_each (mutable) closure. If the ownership could be solved then it solves the immediate problem.

Comment: @Shepmaster If you need _pause_ the interval stream then it could implemented by using [filer](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.18/futures/stream/trait.Stream.html#method.filter) method between `take_while` and `for_each` parts. Or exactly in `for_each` closure.

Comment: @opensourcegeek So you need to synchronize shard object used for example types from `std::sync::*`

Comment: I tried take_while and it does not interrupt the interval, it still fires on the same schedule, if you put a println!() in the take_while closure this is pretty clear